# How to get random css left and top value in particular section with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have to move a div in all over a section with randomly so how I get random left and top value width javascript or Jquery?

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: Consider adding the code in quesiton

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple! You can do as follows:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("moveableObject");
var parent = obj.parentElement;
obj.style.position = 'absolute';
obj.style.left = (parent.clientWidth*Math.random());
obj.style.top = (parent.clientHeight*Math.random());
```